# Dependancy injection with PHPunit Laravel 5.1

Tags: dependency-injection, phpunit, laravel-5

The project has a Service/repository/contract framework that I'm trying to test with `phpunit`. Dependency injection is done via controller methods by injecting a repository contract (interface). Using service providers the injected contracts are replace with the correct repository.

The problem is I need to access these repositories within the unit testing. Such as in my `RoleTest` class

```js
funciton testSomething(\ExampleNameSpace\Users\Contract\RoleContract $repo){
    
    $service = new RoleService($repo);
  
  //do some fun stuff 
   $ret = $service->doSomething( );
  
  }
```

However this does not work. An error is thrown saying the instance in not correct an empty string was received instead.

I could run.

```js
funciton testSomething( ){
    
    $repo = new \ExampleNameSpace\Users\Repositories\RoleEloquentRepository( );
    $service = new RoleService($repo);
  

  //do some fun stuff 
  $ret = $service->doSomething( );
  
  }
```

Then this would defeat the purpose of dependency inversion. How can I make this work?